# Tensorflow loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss, softmax

There are many loss functions in tensorflow like sigmoid_cross_entropy_logits, softmax_cross_entropy_logits. Could you please write mathematical formulations of these functions? And what is logits? Is it referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) function? And is it applied element wise?

Comment: Formula for sigmoid cross entropy description is in docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits

Answer (score 0):

Please see this example:

```
# tf.nn.softmax computes softmax activations
# softmax = exp(logits) / reduce_sum(exp(logits), dim)
logits = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

# Cross entropy cost/loss
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,
                                             labels=Y_one_hot))
```

The logit is output from your model (before softmax). You can find the full example at https://github.com/hunkim/DeepLearningZeroToAll/blob/master/lab-06-2-softmax_zoo_classifier.py.